# Snakemake: a rule with batched inputs and corresponding outputs

Tags: snakemake

I have the following basic structure of the workflow:

- files are downloaded from a remote server,
- converted locally and then
- analyzed.

One of the analyses is time-consuming, but it scales well if run on multiple input files at a time. The output of this rule is independent of what files are analyzed together as a batch as long as they all share the same set of settings. Upstream and downstream rules operate on individual files, so from the perspective of the workflow, this rule is an outlier. What files are to be run together can told in advance, although ideally if some of the inputs failed to be produced along the way, the rule should be run on a reduced of files.

The following example illustrates the problem:

```py
samples = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
groups = {
    'A': samples[0:3],
    'B': samples[3:6]
}

rule all:
    input:
        expand("done/{sample}.txt", sample = samples)

rule create:
    output:
        "created/{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {wildcards.sample} > {output}"

rule analyze:
    input:
        "created/{sample}.txt"
    output:
        "analyzed/{sample}.txt"
    params:
        outdir = "analyzed/"
    shell:
        """
        sleep 1 # or longer
        parallel md5sum {{}} \> {params.outdir}/{{/}} ::: {input}
        """

rule finalize:
    input:
        "analyzed/{sample}.txt"
    output:
        "done/{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

The rule `analyze` is the one to produce multiple output files from multiple inputs according to the assignment in `groups`. The rules `create` and `finalize` operate on individual files upstream and downstream, respectively.

Is there a way to implement such logic? I'd try like to try to avoid splitting the workflow to accommodate this irregularity.

Note: this question is not related to the similar sounding question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561183).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly. rule `analyze` takes in input files `created/a.txt, created/b.txt, created/c.txt` for group A and gives in output
`analyzed/a.txt, analyzed/b.txt, analyzed/c.txt`. The same for group B so rule `analyze` runs twice, everything else runs 6 times.

If so, I make rule `analyze` output a dummy file signaling that files in group A (or B, etc.) has been analyzed. Downstream rules will take in input this dummy file and will find the corresponding `analyzed/{sample}.txt`available.

Here's your example:

```
samples = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
groups = {
    'A': samples[0:3],
    'B': samples[3:6]
}

# Map samples to groups by inverting dict groups
inv_groups = {}
for x in samples:
    for k in groups:
        if x in groups[k]:
            inv_groups[x] = k

rule all:
    input:
        expand("done/{sample}.txt", sample = samples)

rule create:
    output:
        "created/{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {wildcards.sample} > {output}"

rule analyze:
    input:
        # Collect input for this group (A, B, etc)
        grp= lambda wc: ["created/%s.txt" % x for x in groups[wc.group]]
    output:
        done = touch('created/{group}.done'),
    shell:
        """
        # Code that actually does the job...
        for x in {input.grp}
        do
            sn=`basename $x .txt`
            touch analyzed/$sn.txt
        done
        """

rule finalize:
    input:
        # Get dummy file for this {sample}. 
        # If the dummy exists also the corresponding analyzed/{sample}.txt exists.
        done = lambda wc: 'created/%s.done' % inv_groups[wc.sample],
    output:
        fout= "done/{sample}.txt"
    params:
        fin= "analyzed/{sample}.txt",
    shell:
        "cp {params.fin} {output.fout}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your understanding is correct. It seems that your solution can be adapted to the actual workflow I'm building. I'll come back once I have tested it in real life.