# snakemake: How to log python scripts executed by script directive?

Tags: snakemake

Is there any way to easily save logs coming from snakemake rule executing python script with the `script` directive? The script uses libraries, which already have some integrated logging, and I want to store their logs. I do not want to use `shell` or `run` directive as they both are not so comfortable, when working with python scripts. In addition, I hope that the answer will ask for minimum changes in the python scripts, the main changes being in the `Snakemake` file. Here is the example of code:

````
rule correcting_ids:
    input:
        "assembly_{type}/{sample}/{dataset}/final.fasta"
    output:
        "assembly_{type}/{sample}/{dataset}/final.corrected.fasta"
    log:
        "logs/{sample}/correct_{type}_ids_{dataset}.log"
    script:
        "scripts/correcting_ids.py"```
````

Answer (score 6):

You could redirect all stdout and stderr to the logfile

**python**:

```
import sys

with open(snakemake.log[0], "w") as f:
    sys.stderr = sys.stdout = f
    [rest of the script]
```

**R**:

```
log <- file(snakemake@log[[1]], open="wt")
sink(log)
[rest of script]
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a solution where you can use the logggin module but still capture exceptions:

```
import sys,os
import logging, traceback
logging.basicConfig(filename=snakemake.log[0],
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    )
def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        return

    logger.error(''.join(["Uncaught exception: ",
                         *traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
                         ])
                 )
# Install exception handler
sys.excepthook = handle_exception
```

Comment: Much more elegant way to do this!