# How to log error messages arrising from scripts in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to build a snakemake pipeline with custom python scripts.
Some of my scripts run into errors, leading to a shutdown of the pipeline.
However, while in the shell output I can barely see the end of the python error message that leads to the shutdown, this error is not logged anywhere. It is not logged in the snakemake.log that gets automatically created (only stating which script failed without giving the error message), and adding a "log: " with a folder to the rule that fails only creates an empty log.

Is there a way to access the error message, so I can solve the underlying issue?

Edit:
my current snakemake rule looks like this:

```
rule do_X:
    input: "{Wildcard}_a"
    output: "{wildcard}_b"
    log: out = "{Wildcard}_stdout.log"
         err = "{Wildcardd}_stderr.err"
    shell: python script x.py {input}{output}
```

If the script fails, I recive empty logs,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There's a quick breakdown of how the log directive works in Snakemake here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836723/are-files-defined-in-the-log-section-of-a-snakemake-rule-much-different-from-the

Comment: I tried the solution suggested there, but I only recive empty logs

Answer (score 1):

[The link provided by KeyboardCat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836723/are-files-defined-in-the-log-section-of-a-snakemake-rule-much-different-from-the) seems to work well.

Demonstration adapted from your code and the suggested solution:

Save this as `script_x.py`:

```py
#script_x.py
print("test output in stdout made my script")
#import sys # WITH THIS COMMENTED OUT, YOU'LL GET TRACEBACK IN `test_stderr.err`
sys.stderr.write("This was made from std.err")
with open("test_b", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write("result\n")
```

Then your `Snakefile` is:

```py
with open("test_a", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write("#trigger file")


rule all:
    input: "test_b"

rule do_X:
    input: "{wildcard}_a"
    output: "{wildcard}_b"
    log: out = "{wildcard}_stdout.log",
         err = "{wildcard}_stderr.err"
    shell: 'python script_x.py {input}{output} 2> {log.err} 1> {log.out}'
```

Execute snakemake so it uses the `Snakefile`. It will cause an issue because `script_x.py` has an error in it and fails.

In `test_stderr.err`, you'll see the traceback from when the `script_x.py` errored **because `sys` wasn't imported** as the script was written:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_x.py", line 3, in <module>
    sys.stderr.write("This was made from std.err")
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

If you delete the files `test_a` and remove the `#` from in front of the `import sys` line inside `script_x.py` (line #3), it should run without error now and result in the text `This was made from std.err` showing up in the file `test_stderr.err`.

`test_stdout.log` will always end up with `test output in stdout made by script` in it because it gets created before the line containing the error in the script.

---

You say you tried the solution suggested at [the link provided by KeyboardCat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836723/are-files-defined-in-the-log-section-of-a-snakemake-rule-much-different-from-the); however, what did you actually try? Always best to include the variation you tried in the comment or add an update section to your OP.